# Different formatting for icon next to text

Tags: icon-fonts

I want the icon to line up to the right of the text, like it properly does now, but I don't want the icon to take the formatting of the text. The only way I've been able to get the icon to line up to the right of the text is by including it in the " ".

```
<h1>                        
 Heading

<span>
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-down"></i>
</span>

</h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Eric,

if the .glyphicon span is within the text element, it will automatically inherit the text styling (per CSS rules). However, you can easily create a sub-style for glyphicon specifically:

```
h1 .glyphicon {color:black; font-size:80%;}
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried that. If the styling of the icon (glyphicon) is different from the text (h1), it moves the icon to the next line. I want them to be on the same line.